# HTML collection structure same in all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, htmlcollection

When you search elements using `document.getElementsByTagName()` we get a `HTMLCollection`. If elements have `id`s then output have elements with *index* and with *id*.
[image]

Question is, will this structure remain constant across all browser or will it change?

#### Example

```js
(function() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].children;
  console.log(inputs);
})()
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <input type="text" id="input1" />
  <input type="text" id="input2" />
  <input type="text" id="input3" />
  <input type="text" id="input4" />
</div>
```

Comment: So you say that `inputs.input1.value` works if you have id on input, right? .. but when no id is present that will cause issues and those issues you want to be solved?

Comment: @LGSon my html remains same and I have ID all the time.

Comment: Okay, do you ask if the HTMLCollection always is structured the same so that you can access item either by index or id? .. If yes, then yes, if your elements always have an id.

Comment: Yes that is my question. Apologies if I was not able to make it clear enough. So I will always receive same `HTMLCollection` object right in all browsers. right?

Comment: Why don't you directly query elements by ID? `document.getElementById('input1')`. Id should be unique across your DOM anyway.

Comment: Yes, you should get exactly same HTMLCollection across all browsers.

Comment: Thanks guys for your time and feedback, but it was my stupidity and misunderstanding. I have updated my question with cause and will delete post in few mins

Comment: First question is not bad. Leave it without the last update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If more than one elements matching the string used as an index, you can't rely on browsers doing this equal.

> **Browser compatibility**
>   Different browsers behave differently when there
>   are more than one elements matching the string used as an index (or
>   namedItem's argument). Firefox 8 behaves as specified in DOM 2 and
>   DOM4, returning the first matching element. WebKit browsers and
>   Internet Explorer in this case return another HTMLCollection and Opera
>   returns a NodeList of all matching elements.

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

Comment: This is only an issue if you have duplicate IDs, which you're not supposed to do.

Comment: @Barmar It can be an issue if you have named inputs, like when grouping for example checkboxes and such.